# consul-template file per key-value

Tags: go-templates, consul-template

I have a use case where i need consul template to watch multiple keys at a specific path. The number of keys at that path are variable. For each key under that path, it needs to grab the value and put it in a destination file on the host file system.
Is this achievable using consul-template?

Comment: Do the values need to be in the same destination file, or different destinations? How should the data be formatted within the file?

Comment: @BlakeCovarrubias - Preferably, the values should be in separate files, at the same path on disk. But if that is not possible, concatenating all the values and placing them in one file is also acceptable